# having problems associating a class to a d3 element?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm having problems associating a class to a d3 element. I can set style attributes through the d3 style function like this:

```
d3.select(regionBackground).style('fill','darkgrey');
```

However, I'm not able to set style attributes when using the following approaches:

```
d3.select(regionBackground).attr('class', 'highlightRegionBackground');
d3.select(regionBackground).classed('highlightRegionBackground', true);
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here or how to debug?

*** UPDATE ***

It looks like maybe an css reference may need to be added to the svg:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS

Can you verify if this is the case?  I was assuming that an embedded svg would have access to the css stylesheet that was referenced by the webpage but maybe this was an incorrect assumption. The css file associated with the parent webpage is app.min.css.  I added a reference to this css file as the 2nd line in my svg but not sure if this is a valid reference:

Either way, the class reference still isn't getting resolved. Does d3 provide an alternative way of somehow "injecting" a css link into an svg? Is there some other trick I need to get the svg to know about the css? Or am I misunderstanding the way in which SVG/D3/Webpages work with each other?

Comment: Have you written some css to style the region based on the class? Something like `.higlightRegionBackground { fill; darkgrey; }`.

Comment: First, you have to inspect the DOM to see if the element has or not that class. Most probably it will have the class, that's not the problem. Your problem seems to be the fact that the class doesn't behave as it should... in that case, the comment above mine explains why.

Comment: I've validated that the class exists in the css file for the page.  I've validated that the rendered element has a class attr with the expected class name when the element is rendered.  I've validated that the element is only associated with the expected class.  No problem setting the fill with the d3 style function but the classed function is not working.  More specifically, setting a class attribute to the element is not working.